# How to estimate the number of instances in Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have a map-reduce job to be run on the Amazon EMR. I would like to have up to 400 mappers and reducers and I would like to use either Medium or Large instances. How can I estimate the number of instances I need.

Besides, if one job ends within 2 minutes, let's say, and I run another job which take 4 minutes, will I be charged for 2 hours or that's considered 1 hour?

Comment: How did you calculate the number of mappers/reducers?Are you really going to get any advantage with mappers=400=reducers?It depends on your processing needs. And I didn't get the second part of your question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know if you use the CLI tool to create your Job Flow and add the steps, then you can run both of the steps one after another on the same job flow and they will be counted within the same hour.

I believe if you use the GUI then you can not re-use the job flow and so you may get charged one hour for each job. I haven't tried this though so may be wrong there.

Check this article which is where I got the information:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Mahout+on+Elastic+MapReduce